# Adding two textbox values

Tags: excel, vba

can anybody help me with this vba code. I was trying to add the values in these two textboxes but getting an overflow error message. values were randomly generated using the Int() function and ans was declared as integer

```
addsub.Cells(rowmark, 1).Value = txtbxaddend1.Text
addsub.Cells(rowmark, 2).Value = "+"
addsub.Cells(rowmark, 3).Value = txtbxaddend2.Text
addsub.Cells(rowmark, 4).Value = "="
addsub.Cells(rowmark, 5).Value = Format(txtbxsum.Text, "#,#00,000")

**ans = txtbxaddend1 + txtbxaddend2 <----PROBLEM CODE**

If txtbxsum = ans Then
    addsub.Cells(rowmark, 9).Value = "1"
    Else
        addsub.Cells(rowmark, 9).Value = "0"
End If
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try changing `ans` to `Long`, or better yet `Double` if you are using fractions

Answer (score 0):

use

```
ans = CDbl(IIf(txtbxaddend1 = "", 0, txtbxaddend1)) + CDbl(IIf(txtbxaddend2 = "", 0, txtbxaddend2))
```

to ensure you are not dealing with empty text textboxes and converting not empty values to `Double` numbers

Comment: If the vba `val` of `""` is zero, why not work with that?

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much.